# Using a functional approach to pull data out from series of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

I need to do some additional filtering of the data I'm getting, so that I'm only getting the data that match certain criteria. I'm trying to find a combination of operators I can use to accomplish this via a functional programming approach. I'm thinking perhaps a combination of `filter` and `reduce` might work? Could I simply chain a combination of them together to get the result I'm looking for?

My data structure looks like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "53545",
        "services": [
            {
                "service": "service1",
                "history": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6546",
                        "status": "stage1",
                        "completed": true
                    },
                    {
                        **"_id": "6547",
                        "status": "stage2",
                        "completed": false**
                    }
                  ],
            {
                "service": "service2",
                "history": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6743",
                        "status": "stage3",
                        "completed": false
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "3742",
                        "status": "stage2",
                        "completed": true
                    }
                   ]
                },
                {
                "service": "service3",
                "history": [
                    {
                        "_id": "6448",
                        "status": "stage4",
                        "completed": false
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "4443",
                        "status": "stage1",
                        "completed": true
                    }
              ]
        }
     ]
```

To be clear, here `data`, `services` and `history` are ALL arrays. And in the case of the above data, only one object within "history" should pass the tests, as there is only one object where "status:stage2" and "completed:false". BUT that means that, within the "data" array, this particular object, the one with the "_id": "53545" SHOULD pass, as the tests returned true for it. And ultimately, I'm wanting to return an array, from within the objects within the "data" array, that match like this one does.

Very specifically, in my case, there are always 3 services. Within each of those 3, there might be 1 or as many as 30 or more history objects. I need to look through all 3 "services", and find the history objects where the status is "stage2" and "completed:false". So this should return true if ANY of the three services have a history object with "status:stage2" and "completed:false".

I'm getting tripped up iterating over arrays within arrays.

I could get it directly in this manner:

```
let stage2Data = data.filter(data => data.services[0].history[1].status === 'stage2' && data.services[0].history[1].completed === false);
```

However, I obviously don't know what item number in these various arrays will contain the value I'm looking for. So what's the best way to tackle this? I suppose a series of for-of loops could work as well, but I'd like to use a more functional approach, and was thinking a combination of "filter" and "reduce", or perhaps "map" could work here. How would I only return the objects within the "data" array where "`"status": "stage2"` and `"completed": false` is true for at least one of the objects within the "history" array?

Comment: Add a _complete_ example of your data to the question, along with another object showing the output you want to generate from it. As it is, there isn't enough of the input data shown to really understand its format, and it's hard to guess exactly what you want the output to be.

Comment: To clarify, when I say "complete" I don't mean that if you have a hundred items in an array you need to include all hundred of them. But include at least two or three elements for each array, and make it a complete data object that someone can load into JavaScript without error. The object that's currently in the question is chopped off midway through.

Comment: To add some clarity, only one of the items in the "history" array will ever be set to "completed: false" -- because there is only ever one active stage at a time. So, even if there were 100 objects in the history array, there will only ever be one with "completed: false".

Comment: And what is the expected output? It's really unclear what you want to generate.

Comment: `data` appears to be an array based on the presence of the `[` on that line. But arrays do not have property: value pairs as shown on the next line where you have `"services": [...`. This is not a valid data structure. You really need to post an actual valid JSON or JavaScript object, otherwise everyone is guessing about what your data actually looks like.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I mis-copied it. I edited the above code to make it correct. 'data' is an array.

Comment: I edited my code to offer a little more clarity on the data structure. But to clarify further, "data", "services" and "history" are ALL arrays.

Comment: OK, so `data` is an array of objects. Each of those objects has a `services` property which is also an array of objects. Each of _those_ objects has a `history` property which is again an array of objects as shown above. Are `services` and `history` the only properties of interest inside their respective objects? Or could there be other properties with other names that you also need to look at?

Comment: Yes, in this case, "services" and "history" are the only items of interest inside their respective objects

Comment: Very specifically, in my case, there are always 3 services. Within each of those 3, there might be 1 or as many as 30 or more history objects. I need to look through all 3 "services", and find the history objects where the status is "stage2" and "completed:false", and return only those in an array.

Comment: So I'm returning the object if ANY one or more of the three services have a history object with "status:stage2" and "completed:false".

Comment: You still don't have valid data in your question. For example, there are mismatched `[` and `}` characters, and it's still chopped off at the end. Can you _please_ post a valid and complete data structure? Put it in a snippet (use the <> icon in the editor) and add a `console.log` call at the end to display the data, and then run the snippet so you know it parses correctly and represents the data you want.

Comment: Edited and added code above as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been going back and forth in the comments to try to get a valid data structure in your question. Let me give you a simple example of how you can make this much easier for everyone.

First, use the snippet button at the top of the editor box to create a snippet. It's the icon that looks like a typical "folded corner" document icon with `<>` inside it.

This will open up a popup box with places for HTML/CSS/JavaScript code. Ignore the HTML and CSS boxes and paste your data object into the JavaScript box.

Because it's not JavaScript "as is", wrap it inside an assignment statement to get a JavaScript variable that you can work with.

Then add a `console.log` statement at the end to display the data. Use the **Run** button to make sure the code actually parses and runs and displays the data correctly. Once you do that, it will be *much* easier for people to help you.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
const input = {
    "data": [
        {
            "one": "two"
        },
        {
            "three": "four"
        }
    ]
};

console.log( JSON.stringify( input, null, 4 ) );
```

Click the **Run code snippet** button above to see this example run. Notice how it prints out the same data structure that I used above.

If you do the same in your question, this will force you to clean up your data so that it is actually valid. Then you are giving people something they can work with.

One other note: don't be hung up on trying to do this in a "functional" manner. It's very likely that you will get more understandable code by creating an empty array with `let output = [];`, then using `.forEach()` on each of your nested arrays (or `for...of` loops if you are targeting the latest browsers), and using `output.push()` on each matching element.

To illustrate, assuming I understand your data structure correctly (and assuming you wrap it inside an `input` variable as in my simplified example) it might look something like this:

```
let output = [];
input.data.forEach( function( dataItem ) {
    dataItem.services.forEach( function( service ) {
        service.history.forEach( function( historyItem ) {
            if( ! historyItem.completed  && historyItem.status == "stage2" ) {
                output.push( historyItem );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or using `for...of` loops:

```
let output = [];
for( let dataItem of input.data ) {
    for( let service of dataItem.services ) {
        for( let historyItem of service.history ) {
            if( ! historyItem.completed  && historyItem.status == "stage2" ) {
                output.push( historyItem );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these are untested, of course. And either way it's not fancy, but it seems pretty easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you. What would a simple implementation of a nested array check using the methods you describe (using forEach()) look like?

Comment: I added a couple of _untested_ examples, one using `.forEach()`, the other using `for...of` loops. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Much appreciated, Michael. This approach looks promising.

Comment: My pleasure, Ademo. Sorry I sounded a little impatient in the comments on the question. :-) It's just that it is really helpful to provide a runnable snippet in the question along with a sample of the expected output. The nice thing about the runnable snippet is that people can copy it into an answer and then tweak it from there. It also makes sure that the sample input data is valid and has the correct structure that you need to work with. Runnable code snippets are great for this.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want the result data, here's a start for you.  You can brute-force this with a few nested filters:

```
result = data.filter((datum) => {
  return datum.services.filter((service) => {
    return service.history.filter((h) => {
      return h.completed && h.status === "stage2"
    }).length > 0;
  }).length > 0;
});
```

tl;dr - Filter the main list by any datum that has services that have at least one history record that was completed in stage 2.

Working fiddle:  http://jsbin.com/jozujezidu/edit?js,console,output

If you want your resultant array to only have the history records that pass the filter, you'll have to modify the code.  Plus, this is an On^3, so if this data can be enormous, you should probably modify the approach.  But this should get you going.

Don't worry about being militant functional.  If you can come to a working solution that people can understand and maintain, then that's a good start.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right direction. But, yes, I do need to only pull out the records that pass the test. And right now I'm just getting back my original list. So I'm looking this over to see what I'd have to tweak to only get passing results returned to me.

Comment: So, just so I'm clear, what exactly is your code returning in the above example? Also, in your fiddle example, both of the objects you created had "completed" set to "true", whereas one should be "false". And when I change one to be "completed: false" I get an empty array returned.

Answer (score 0):

A filter operation will be based on a predicate matching your values.

If you are wanting a list of the service objects try this approach:

`let result = data[0].services.filter((item) => item.history.some((h) => h.status=='stage2' && h.completed==false));`

Comment: But this would only get at the first object in the data array, right? Whereas I need to iterate through all items in that array.

Comment: there was no way to know from the question how many objects are in the array at the top level, you would just need to add another filter in the case where there are more than one object in data[] array

Comment: Fair enough. I guess my main question was how to filter through multiple, nested levels of arrays - and implicitly that means not knowing what element in the array I need to target - for any of those arrays - ahead of time.

Comment: sma has a good answer and the use of filter with a length check, is similar to the some() method in both es6 and lodash et.al.

Comment: I'm also looking to tweak his code, because I do need to pull out just the values that pass the tests, and his code isn't currently doing this.